# Jmeter is not running from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

Please check the version details below

```
Jenkins - Jenkins 2.387.1
Jmeter  - 5.5

Java
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.38+22-SA (build 17.0.5+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.38+22-SA (build 17.0.5+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I am able to run Jmeter from my machine without any issue and couldn't run from Jenkins which is installed on local.

[image]

Please throw some light on this issue...

Comment: You can test this by creating a simple job in jenkins that running bat command `java -version`

Comment: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apache JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a **100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

It means that you need to have [Java Runtime Environment](https://www.ibm.com/topics/jre) in order to be able to launch JMeter on any machine.

So you need to:

1. Install JRE (or even better [JDK](https://openjdk.org/)) version 8+
2. Add "bin" folder of your JRE (or JDK) to your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)

Comment: I have installed Java 17 jdk zulu version. Jmeter working fine without any issues but jenkins fails which also installed on the same machine.. i will install java 11 and try..

Answer (score 0):

After the downgrade from java 17 to 11 , Jenkins started working fine.